# MYSQL num rows error

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I am trying to use a piece of code which I have used before to quickly test out an idea, however I Keep getting the following error.

Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM masterip_details WHERE timedate(datetime) = CURDATE() and ip_address='$ip_address");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if( $num_rows > 0 ) {
```

Comment: I never get heard when I say this but... You cannot assume that all queries succeed and start guessing otherwise. You need to do proper error checking. There's an example right in [mysql_query()](http://php.net/mysql_query) manual page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
("SELECT * FROM masterip_details WHERE timedate(datetime) = CURDATE() AND ip_address='$ip_address'")
```

You missed an ' at the end of your SQL-Statement and you should write "AND" uppercased, since all other SQL-Keywords are written uppercased (not essential, but easier to read).

Maybe the missing ' will fix your Query.

Comment: Uppercasing `AND` isn't strictly necessary.

Answer (score 1):

That's probably because the SQL request failed. Try to append `or die(mysql_error())` next to your mysql_query, like this :

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM masterip_details WHERE timedate(datetime) = CURDATE() and ip_address='$ip_address") or die(mysql_error());
```

This should output the error so that you can fix it.

EDIT: And I can also give you a clue of what that error could be. At the end of your request, you're not closing the single quote after `$ip_address`

Answer (score 0):

There is a sintax error in your query, you are missing a quote right after `$ip_address` just change to

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  masterip_details WHERE timedate(datetime) = CURDATE() and ip_address='$ip_address'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  You are missing one single quote...

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM masterip_details WHERE timedate(datetime) = CURDATE() and ip_address='$ip_address' ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You keep getting that error because your query is wrong:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM masterip_details WHERE timedate(datetime) = CURDATE() and ip_address='$ip_address"
```

is missing a quote after `$ip_address`

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a single quote here `and ip_address='$ip_address'")`

Take a look at this:
[Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)